# Is there any official guide to configure rails for lightweight json rest services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Jeff Dean from pivotal labs [wrote about it](http://pivotallabs.com/users/jdean/blog/articles/1419-building-a-fast-lightweight-rest-service-with-rails-3-). I is there any official guides for that? Perhaps if there is a newer blog post that would be also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but rather an alternative :-)

You might wanna look at [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape). It's a Sinatra-like framework for building REST APIs :-)

I discovered it a few days ago. It looks promising. I'm going to use it in my next project.

Comment: Looks promising. But currently we need to optimize existing rails version.

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov: Then I'd go with that article. It looks ok too :-)